# Making a "page loading" graphic stop using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form which after submitting I would like a brief "spinning wheel" type page loading to appear while the form processes.  The typical eye-candy to ensure that a person knows the click went through and won't reclick.

I have my form, and I have the below code:

```
<div style="display:none" id="pleasewait"><img src="images/loading.gif" /></div>
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
    $("#pleasewait").show();
    $(".submit").load("contact.php", function(){ $("#pleasewait").hide(); });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that this form is posting to PHP SELF and once clicked, while the lovely little spinning "Please wait" appears and looks great, the form never posts...it just hangs.  I tried looking to see if JQuery could tell "if POST" but that appears tricky.  Is there a good way to change the last line of the function so that it will recognize the form has been posted and stop the spinner?  I think the problem is the second ".submit" section...I just can't figure out what I need to do.

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Comment: the `load()` function loads the generated HTML from the URL specified and appends it into the selected element.  You need to use the `ajax` method.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution.  At first it was very choppy but I realized that preloading the image solved that.

First, the css for #pleasewait is {display:none;} which hides it until needed.

In the head of the page, between script tags, I added this code:

```
function showimage()
{
document.getElementById('pleasewait').style.display = "block";
}
```

In the body of the document, I added a div with the animated gif:

```
<div id="pleasewait"><img src="spinningwheel.gif" /></div>
```

Then I just used (attached to the Submit):

```
onClick="showimage()"
```

This works exactly how I hoped it would, and spins the wheel either as long as the page loads to PHP Self or to another page.  I'm not including the code that preloaded the image so that it works smoothly.  Hopefully this will help someone else with this same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the contact.php page not submitting to it.  Also, you should not use a click event on a button to submit the form.  Add your code to the submit event of the form itself. You want something more like this.  *FYI: I have not tested this code!*

```
$(function() {
  $("#myform").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#pleasewait').show();
    $.ajax({ 
      url:'contact.php',
      data : $('#myform').serialize(),
      success : function ( data ) {
        $('#pleasewait').hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  I tried the code above and it didn't work...the form didn't submit, nor did the image appear.  Do I need to do something (link to a library?) to support .ajax?

Comment: Sorry, correction!  It WORKS...but only for a brief second.  That's actually fine because in this case I suspect the processing only takes that long.  What made me think it had hung is that it never loads the confirmation -- I have a php "if POST" statement that processes the form, validates, and displays a "Thank you, your comments have been sent." message and THAT part is not working.  So I think what's missing is the actual _submitting_ of the form.  The display of the image seems to work okay...and it stops, so I'm a step closer!  Just not quite all the way...

Comment: The above code sends data to contact.php via `get`.  You can change that to `post` easily enough.  You could add your success message as a `<div>` as well and `show()` it when the success function is called.  http://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

The third parameter to `.load()` accepts a function to run on complete.

So you're solution should be:

`$(".submit").load("contact.php", {}, function(){ $("#pleasewait").hide(); });`

Comment: You are correct about the `load()` function but he is actually trying to submit to the contact.php page not load it into the submit element.